# setInterval on a jQuery deferred object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am trying to better understand the use of deferred objects in jQuery.

The `getData` method below fetches some data asynchronously. When done, it should be displayed to some predefined (`log`) section by `addToChart`. This should happen periodically, hence my using `setInterval` inside `getData`'s `done` handler.

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
getData().done(addToChart, function() {
    setInterval(getData, 1000);
});

function addToChart(data) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerText += data;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});
```

In above code, `getData` seems to get called only once. How do I let it be called periodically?

Also, is there any way to actually debug this code, rather than run it and scratch my head why it doesn't behave as expected? (I'm new to JavaSCript, in case you wonder). I stepped through the code using the Firefox debugger but that didn't help.

Comment: `setTimeout` will only run once. You want `setInterval`. Beyond that, what is not working?

Comment: Yes, @KevinBoucher is correct. And this question might be a duplicate. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/729943/4040563

Comment: @KevinBoucher Right, I changed the call to `setInterval`. However, it still executes only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout is used to delay a function
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

What you want to use is setInterval
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

So looking at what you're trying to do, i would do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv',
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(addToChart);
    }

    function addToChart(data) {
        document.getElementById('log').innerText += data;
    }

    setInterval(getData, 1000);
});
```

Comment: done syntax is incorrect. You are invoking `addToChart` immediately

Comment: @charlietfl just fixed that, thanks for catching that

Comment: This works, but I wonder why things break if I try to decouple the data handler from the ajax request, i.e. I move the `done` handler out of the `getData` function: `getData.done(addToChart);`

Comment: @badweathercoder i haven't tested but u can decouple it further if you want to, moving `done` handler outside, so getData needs to return the ajax object `function getData() {return $.ajax(....);}`, then in the setInterval like this: `setInterval(function() { getData().done(addToChart); }, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Any idea why this doesn't work: `setInterval(getData, 1000); getData.done(addToChart);`, while your suggestion `setInterval(function() { getData().done(addToChart); }, 1000);` works?

Comment: Because when you call `setInterval(getData, 1000)` it will only execute getData and doesn't acknowledge the callback for done, which you're calling on the next line and this is not connected to the setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a while loop :

```
while (condition) {
    code block to be executed
}
```

or the do/while loop :

```
do {
    code block to be executed
}
while (condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `done` inside the function so it will get called every time the function does and request succeeds

```
function getData() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv',
      type: 'GET'
    })
    .then(addToChart)
    .always(function() {
      setTimeout(getData, 1000);
    });
}
```

Alternate approach is wrap what you are currently doing in a new function

```
function getData() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv',
    type: 'GET'
  });
}

function loadChart() {
  getData()
    .then(addToChart)
    .always(function() {
      setTimeout(loadChart, 1000);
    });

}

loadChart()
```

Comment: This seems similar to doing it the "old" jQuery way, where you define a `success` as success handler. I'd like to decouple the callback handling from the AJAX request as much as possible.

Comment: Then use a separate function that calls `getData` and put the timeout in that function and call the new function instead each time

Comment: See alternative approach